# regex - getting last occurance not first - why?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have problem with reg ex. in PHP
I have string like:

```
sdfsfds dsfdsh kj <img src="cid:sdfsdf/img.jpg@23232"> sdfd sfdhg sdjhg sdfsfds dsfdsh kj <img src="cid:sdfsdf/img.jpg@23232"> sdfd sfdhg sdjhg
```

I want to grab everything between 'cid:' and '">' and replace it with something else.
Here is my reg ex:

```
cid:.*img\.jpg.*\"
```

What do I get in return??

```
cid:sdfsdf/img.jpg@23232"> sdfd sfdhg sdjhg sdfsfds dsfdsh kj <img src="cid:sdfsdf/img.jpg@23232"
```

insead of double

```
cid:sdfsdf/img.jpg@23232
```

why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is greedy.  Use non-greedy quantifiers by adding a `?` after them:

```
cid:.*?img\.jpg.*?\"
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is greedy, `.*` will match the longest possible string.  Many regex dialects allow for `.*?` to instead match the shortest possible string, or you can limit it so it doesn't straddle a particular boundary, e.g. with `cid:[^">]*img\.jpg[^">]*"`

Comment: The other answers are very good, but I give this a +1 for showing the alternative: `cid:[^">]*img\.jpg[^">]*"`

Answer (score 0):

Thy this:

```
/<img\s.*?\bsrc="cid:(.*?)".*?>/
```